# inner join with m/n relationship tables and sum of a certain column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have [three tables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acd0cb/5)

- codes
- users
- codes_users

`codes` contains codes which should get assigned to a specific `users` the `codes_users` holds the connection information.

```
SELECT users.*, 
       codes.code 
FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN (codes 
                  INNER JOIN codes_users 
                          ON codes.id = codes_users.code_id) 
              ON users.id = codes_users.user_id
```

I've manages to display the code with the user in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acd0cb/1

But when I like to count the downloads I get only one result:

```
SELECT users.*, 
       codes.code, 
       Sum(users.downloads) AS _downloadscount 
FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN (codes 
                  INNER JOIN codes_users 
                          ON codes.id = codes_users.code_id) 
              ON users.id = codes_users.user_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acd0cb/2

and also I like to have the download count of each user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query needs a group by in the end, telling DB that you want a count **per user**

```
SELECT users.*, 
       codes.code, 
       Sum(users.downloads) AS _downloadscount 
FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN (codes 
                  INNER JOIN codes_users 
                          ON codes.id = codes_users.code_id) 
              ON users.id = codes_users.user_id 
GROUP  BY users.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT users.*, codes.code, SUM(users.downloads) AS _downloadscount FROM users
LEFT JOIN
    (codes INNER JOIN codes_users ON codes.ID = codes_users.code_id)
     ON users.ID = codes_users.user_id
group by users.id
```