# Move a column into a dedicate table

Tags: mysql, sql

In addition to **[this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451764/inner-join-with-m-n-relationship-tables-and-sum-of-a-certain-column)** I like to move the download column into a separate table "`downloads`" which contains the info and timestamp of a certain download

Here's **[the Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ca2b)**

As a result I like to have

```
ID  referer             domain              code       downloads
=========================================================================
1   example.com/siteA   example.com         codeone    2
2   example2.com/siteA  example2.com        (null)     2
3   example.com/siteB   example.com         codetwo    0
4   example2.com/siteB  example2.com        (null)     2
```

This is my **[current attempt](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ca2b/1)** without the downloads column

```
SELECT users.*, 
       codes.code
       FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN (codes 
                  INNER JOIN codes_users 
                          ON codes.id = codes_users.code_id) 
              ON users.id = codes_users.user_id 
GROUP  BY users.id;
```

**EDIT**

furthermore I like to [group by the domain](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ca2b/19) with

```
GROUP  BY users.domain;
```

How do I get the downloads count of the referer:

```
ID  referer             domain        code      dl_for_domain   dl_for_referer
==================================================================================
1   example.com/siteA   example.com   codeone   2               2
2   example2.com/siteA  example2.com  (null)    4               2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `GROUP BY` is fine for the purpose, just join also `downloads` and `COUNT(downloads.*)`.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ca2b/4/0

```
SELECT users.*, 
       codes.code,
       COUNT(downloads.ID)
       FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN (codes 
                  INNER JOIN codes_users 
                          ON codes.id = codes_users.code_id) 
              ON users.id = codes_users.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN downloads ON
           users.id = downloads.user_id
GROUP  BY users.id;
```

To get into more detail about `GROUP BY`: in general in SQL, you need to `GROUP BY` *every variable* that is not aggregated, i.e. in our case `COUNT()`'ed. The following would be best and close to what you need:

```
SELECT users.referer,
       users.domain, 
       codes.code,
       COUNT(downloads.ID)
       FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN (codes 
                  INNER JOIN codes_users 
                          ON codes.id = codes_users.code_id) 
              ON users.id = codes_users.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN downloads ON
           users.id = downloads.user_id
GROUP  BY users.referer,
       users.domain, 
       codes.code;
```

And let me go into two more details about MySQL in particular:

- MySQL has a "lazy" implementation of `GROUP BY`, that means that if you don't include an unaggregated variable in the `GROUP BY` but it is unique within groups, that is valid. This is why your and my first code is valid in MySQL but isn't on other systems. See [GROUP BY query that works in MySQL is rejected by PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995609/group-by-query-that-works-in-mysql-is-rejected-by-postgresql) and in particular the comment and link on 'lazy' impementation.
- On the upside, MySQL supports `WITH ROLLUP` which might or might not be useful for you if you aggregate on different fields. In case of `ROLLUP` the order of variables matter so do experiment with it. See:

  ```
  SELECT codes.code,
         users.domain,
         users.referer,
         COUNT(downloads.ID)
         FROM   users 
         LEFT JOIN (codes 
                    INNER JOIN codes_users 
                            ON codes.id = codes_users.code_id) 
                ON users.id = codes_users.user_id 
         LEFT JOIN downloads ON
             users.id = downloads.user_id
  GROUP  BY codes.code,
            users.domain,
            users.referer           
  WITH ROLLUP;
  ```

In this case `NULL` variables mean an aggregate for *all* rows independent of that variable. (Which reminds me that first you should make sure all these variables are `NOT NULL` before using `ROLLUP` to avoid ambiguity.

**EDIT**:

You also request `GROUP BY` referers but also include sums for each domain. This could be very easy in a system supporting window functions (`COUNT(downloads.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY domain`) but in MySQL maybe best is to build it up from two queries.

You can first define a view containing all the information:

```
create view v as
select users.domain,
       downloads.ID,
       referer,
       code, 
       downloads.user_id
FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN (codes 
                  INNER JOIN codes_users 
                          ON codes.id = codes_users.code_id) 
              ON users.id = codes_users.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN downloads ON
           users.id = downloads.user_id;
```

Then just collect both by referer and by domain data from this view:

```
select * from
(
    SELECT
        referer,
        domain, 
        code,
        COUNT(user_id) AS dl_for_referer
    FROM v
    GROUP  BY referer
) group_referrer JOIN
(
    SELECT
        domain, 
        COUNT(ID) AS dl_for_domain
    FROM
        v
    GROUP BY domain
) group_domain ON
    group_referrer.domain=group_domain.domain;
```

see also http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/131a0/2/0

Comment: Ok this works in the example, thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't in my application. The `COUNT(downloads.ID)`always returns the amount of rows in the table. Better would be something like `COUNT WHERE user_id = download.user_id`

Comment: Can you change your example to reflect this difference? -- Are you sure that the JOIN to the downloads table is successful? Double check if it is only joining according to the needed user_id.

Comment: Ok, my fault: If I [group by domain](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ca2b/9) I get the total for a certain domain. How do I get the amount of the referer?

Comment: @revaxarts i have also edited my response about group by and rollup.

Comment: Can you complete [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ca2b/35) to get the mentioned result?

Comment: No, I expect two rows like the very last codeblock in my questions. Thanks for your afford!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49138/discussion-between-daniel-sparing-and-revaxarts)

Answer (score 1):

Try below SQL:

```
SELECT u.id, u.referer, u.domain, c.code, count(d.id) FROM users u
LEFT JOIN codes_users cu ON cu.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN codes c ON c.id = cu.code_id
LEFT JOIN downloads d ON d.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ca2b/25/0

GROUP BY DOMAIN

```
SELECT u.id, u.referer, u.domain, c.code, count(d.id) downloads FROM users u
LEFT JOIN codes_users cu ON cu.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN codes c ON c.id = cu.code_id
LEFT JOIN downloads d ON d.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.domain with rollup
having u.domain is not null
```

OUTPUT

```
ID  REFERER                 DOMAIN            CODE          DOWNLOADS
1   example.com/siteA       example.com       codeone       2
2   example2.com/siteA      example2.com      (null)        4
```